# How to improve performance of making an Exponentially Weighted Correlation Matrix?

Tags: performance-tuning, compile, time-series, finance

I would like to make an Exponentially Weighted version of `Correlation` (similar to https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.ewmcov.html).

My code is slow, how can I speed it up?

---

**Vector Input**

To do this I need to first calculate Exponentially Weighted Standard Deviations and Covariance first.

```
stDevEWMA[list_List, c_Real] :=  Sqrt[ExponentialMovingAverage[list^2, c]];
covarianceEWMA[list1_List, list2_List, c_Real] := ExponentialMovingAverage[list1*list2, c];
```

So:

```
correlationEWMA[list1_List, list2_List, c_Real] :=
    Last@covarianceEWMA[list1, list2, c]/( Last@stDevEWMA[list1, c]*Last@stDevEWMA[list2, c]);
```

Some sample data:

```
data = {
  {0.0025368051270555636`, 0.01974194384702299`, -0.010201971309342195`,
    0.01624296059783248`, -0.048181859416501105`, -0.02555248369410701`,
    0.011751625716882819`, 0.0009874825413342947`, 0.036892999971493534`,
    0.02918373607710656`, -0.0031430425630201153`, -0.009547744422772064`
  },
  {0.0022753767547250003`, -0.01829191934114127`, 0.023909982049822087`,
    -0.01070484309176889`, 0.04987999448021485`,  0.032412474523605406`,
    -0.015221863975058536`,0.001941816623721282`, -0.05757831949596204`,
    -0.014116594610274036`, -0.020368701580867676`, 0.0011471796777184906`
  },
  {
    0.010647727268083162`, -0.016147947259917972`, 0.011578090975155497`,
    -0.025274169235405375`, 0.05823646283591277`, 0.041215591847145294`,
    -0.02312948393856451`, -0.021664036631744432`, -0.023133482190751398`,
    -0.014041150237408373`, -0.01717626765563618`, -0.02935551962838745`
  }
};

ListLinePlot[data,PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

The first two paths look like they are negatively correlated

```
correlationEWMA[data[[1]], data[[2]], 0.1]
```

> -0.872287

---

When doing the calculation with two vectors as an input, I am about 20x slower than `Correlation`

```
(correlationEWMA[data[[1]], data[[2]], 0.1] // RepeatedTiming // First)/
 (Correlation[data[[1]], data[[2]]] // RepeatedTiming // First)
```

> 23.4523

Things are even worse when I adapt this to take a matrix as an input...

---

**Matrix Input**

My strategy is too loop through the upper triangular portion of the correlation matrix and then populate the remaining fields as correlation matrices are symmetric and have `1` on the diagonal

```
correlationMatrixEWMA[mat_List, c_Real] :=
 With[
  {
   n = Dimensions[mat][[2]]
   },
  Module[
   {
    m = ConstantArray[0, {n, n}]
    },
   Do[
    Do[
     m[[row, col]] = 
      correlationEWMA[mat[[All, row]], mat[[All, col]], c]
     ,
     {col, row + 1, n}
     ],
    {row, 1, n - 1}
    ];
   m + Transpose[m] + IdentityMatrix[n]
   ]
  ];

correlationMatrixEWMA[dataTransposed, 0.1] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

This approach is about 40x slower.

```
(correlationMatrixEWMA[dataTransposed, 0.1]; // RepeatedTiming // 
   First)/(Correlation[dataTransposed]; // RepeatedTiming // First)
```

> 37.3897

Is there a cleverer "Mathematica" way I can do this? Eg to make use of built in functions that are already fast (maybe `WeightedData`?) or do I have to go through the `Compile` route ?

Comment: I don't think that your definition of `covarianceEWMA` makes any sense because it does not center `list1` and `list2` in any way before `ExponentialMovingAverage` is applied.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, will check that

Comment: covar(i) = [ a(i) * b(i) * alpha ] + [ covar(i-1) * (1-alpha) ] tallies with the definition I am using. Is this what you disagree with? I am not sure what you mean by centering the list.

Comment: I meant that $\mathrm{cov}(X,Y)$ is $\mathrm{E} \big( (X - \mathrm{E}(X)) \, (Y - \mathrm{E}(Y)) \big)$ and not $\mathrm{E}( X, Y )$.

Comment: I see what you mean. But are you ok with the Variance definition I use ? i.e `ExponentialMovingAverage[list^2, c]`

Comment: No, I‘m not okay with this definition of variance as variance of a RV should be just the covariance with itself.

Comment: I am looking at something like this : https://numxl.com/blogs/exponentially-weighted-moving-average-ewma/

Comment: I am not going to do the math research for you. I am just telling you that your definitions are probably not very meaningful.

Comment: I am not expecting you to, just pointing out this definition is used in other applications :)

Comment: At some point in the cited text, the authors say "Next, let’s assume $\bar r = 0$", which means that they use random variables with zero expectation. If you have data that is sampled from a RV with nonzero expectation, then you have to subtract the mean first. I cannot know whether the data that you want to use in all this is centered or not. Thus my warning.

Comment: Thanks, I do appreciate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Albeit I doubt that your implementation of `correlationEWMA` is correct, here is an equivalent implementation of it via `Compile`"

```
cCorrelationEWMA = Compile[{{a, _Real, 1}, {b, _Real, 1}, {q, _Real}},
   Block[{result, n, factor, p, sumaa, sumab, sumbb, ai, bi},
    n = Min[Length[a], Length[b]];
    result = Table[0., {n}];
    p = 1. - q;
    factor = q/p;
    sumaa = 0.;
    sumbb = 0.;
    sumab = 0.;
    Do[
     factor *= p;
     ai = Compile`GetElement[a, i];
     bi = Compile`GetElement[b, i];
     sumaa += ai ai factor;
     sumab += ai bi factor;
     sumbb += bi bi factor;
     , {i, n, 2, -1}];
    
    factor *= p;
    factor /= q;
    ai = Compile`GetElement[a, 1];
    bi = Compile`GetElement[b, 1];
    
    sumaa += ai ai factor;
    sumab += ai bi factor;
    sumbb += bi bi factor;
    
    sumab/Sqrt[sumaa sumbb]

    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];
```

Timing test and correctness check:

```
n = 10000000;
a = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, n];
b = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, n];
q = 0.1;

result0 = correlationEWMA[a, b, q]; // RepeatedTiming // First
result1 = cCorrelationEWMA[a, b, q]; // RepeatedTiming // First
Correlation[a, b]; // RepeatedTiming // First
(result0 - result1)/result0
```

> 0.825671
>
> 0.0196983
>
> 0.0119216
>
> -4.11029*10^-15

So it seems to provide the correct result in less that twice the amount of time spent in `Correlation`.

Comment: Thank you. Intuitively do you think the quickest way to build the matrix is a Compiled  loop through each element? I have tried making a listable function that maps onto a vector of the upper triangular coordinates (`{{1, 2}, {1, 3},...`) and then building the upper triangular matrix from the results but I am not seeing much of a speed up.

Comment: Turns out you can't `Compile` a `ConstantArray` but using your method inside the loop is very fast. +1

Comment: Instead of ConstantArray you can use things like Table[0., {n}], Table[0.,{m}, {n}], etc.

Comment: Thanks, very fast now